# Create nested JSON structure with Coldfusion

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldbox

I've been converting CF structs etc to JSON for a while now, and all good. Coldbox in particular makes this really easy.

However, I am currently working with a jQuery Datatable and need to pass it jSON in the format below.

I am starting with an array of objects.

I only want certain properties in each object to go into the final JSON String.

I'm running around in circles and possibly totally overcomplicating converting my data into this format JSON.  Can anyone help, or suggest an easy way I might be able to do this..

Also worth mentioning I am building this in coldbox.  Coldfusion 9.

```
{ "aaData": [ [ "Test1", "test@test1", "444444444", "<i class=''icon-pencil icon-large'' data-id=''s1''></i>" ],[ "Test2", "test@test2", "555555555", "<i class=''icon-pencil icon-large'' data-id=''s2''></i>" ],[ "Test3", "test@test3", "666666666", "<i class=''icon-pencil icon-large'' data-id=''s3''></i>" ] ]}
```

Many Thanks!

======================================================

Here is the code that game we what I needed:

```
var dataStruct = structNew();
var dataArray = arrayNew(1);
var subsArray = arrayNew(1);
var subs = prc.org.getSubscribers();

for (i=1; i<=arrayLen(subs); i++){
    arrayAppend(subsArray,"#subs[i].getName()#");
    arrayAppend(subsArray,"#subs[i].getEmail()#");
    arrayAppend(subsArray,"#subs[i].getMobile()#");
    arrayAppend(subsArray,"<i class='icon-pencil icon-large' data-id='s#subs[i].getID()#'></i>");
    arrayAppend(dataArray,subsArray);
    arrayClear(subsArray);
};
structInsert(dataStruct,'aaData',dataArray);    
event.renderData('json',dataStruct);
```

Comment: What version of ColdFusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so you've got an array which has objects, and the objects contain all the properties which you need to end up in this JSONed array, yeah?

So do this:

```
create a new array
loop over the array of objects
    create a struct
    put all the values from each object you need to go into the JSON; be mindful to use associative array notation when setting the keys, to perserve the case of the keys
    append the struct to the new array
/loop
serializeJson the new array
```

I don't think there's any simpler way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks Cameron. That's what I was going to do, however the data on the output JSON isn't "name" : "value". It's just a list ov values. Serializing a struct will place both the key and value into the JSON.

Comment: In that case, just replace the "create a struct" step with "create an array", pulling the value for each index of the array from the original object in order to make sure the values are in the correct order.